# How to change language in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea

It seems like silly question, but I cannot find it anywhere in settings. How to change the language??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you mean the IDE language? Seems like [you cannot](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/message/5307040#5307040), unless you [localize it yourself](http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/reference_guide/localization_guide.html)...