# IntelliJ plugin localization

Tags: intellij-idea, plugins, localization

I'm creating a plugin for `Intellij IDEA`. Following found tutorial now I have pretty simple working plugin. But my problem is the fact I don't know how to maintain localization for my actions.

Now I've got `plugin.xml` file with following `actions` tag:

```
<actions>
    <group id="MyPlugin.TopMenu"
           text="_MyPlugin"
           description="My plugin toolbar menu">
        <add-to-group group-id="MainMenu" anchor="last"/>
        <action id="MyAction"
                class="actions.MyAction"
                text="_MyAction"
                description="MyAction"/>
    </group>
</actions>
```

This code means that my group and action will be shown as `"_MyPlugin"` and `"_MyAction"` regardless localization.

I found how to create resouces bundle and did it. Now I have `strings.xml` (as I used to for Android) with following content:

```
<properties>
    <entry key="ActionName">_MyAction</entry>
</properties>
```

Another resource file called `strings_ru.xml` is combined with it into `Resource Bundle`, so I don't think I did something wrong with it.

**I want to use resource reference** to set `text` tag for my group and its actions. Is it even possible? If not should I create and register actions in runtime?

Comment: IntelliJ does not seem to support localization on the IDE level, I have encountered hardcoded strings in a couple plugins. I cannot give you a solution unfortunately - I assume you have been through [this](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206349009-How-to-change-the-language-of-IDE-from-english-to-german-) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12324614/how-to-change-language-in-intellij-idea), so registering [the actions from code](http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics/action_system.html?search=action#registering-actions-from-code) is the way